# Rails DB Migration - How To Drop a Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rollback, drop-table

I added a table that I thought I was going to need, but now no longer plan on using it. How should I remove that table?

I've already run migrations, so the table is in my database. I figure `rails generate migration` should be able to handle this, but I haven't figured out how yet.

I've tried:

```
rails generate migration drop_tablename
```

but that just generated an empty migration.

What is the "official" way to drop a table in Rails?

Comment: Since `rails generate migration` has command-line options for generating migration code for creating tables, adding or changing columns, etc., it would be nice if it also had an option for dropping a table -- but it doesn't. Sure, writing the `up` part is simple -- just call `drop_table` -- but the `down` part, generating the table again, might not always be so simple, especially if the schema of the table in question has been changed by migrations after its initial creation. Maybe someone should suggest to the developers of Rails that adding such an option would be a good idea.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti How about just copy and paste the current table definition from schema.rb? I do it this way all the time...

Comment: @João Soares: OK, I guess that works. However, it would be nice if the process could be automated, so that you could just give a `rake` migration-creation command, with the name of a table as a parameter, that would produce the needed `up` and `down` functions.

Comment: I opened a PR on github for this: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48729

It is not yet reversible (I have same concerns as @TeemuLeisti)  but maybe someone else can improve that.

Answer (score 708, accepted):

You won't always be able to simply generate the migration to already have the code you want. You can create an empty migration and then populate it with the code you need.

You can find information about how to accomplish different tasks in a migration here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

More specifically, you can see how to drop a table using the following approach:

```
drop_table :table_name
```

Comment: This worked for me too. But on full migrations (installing from scratch) the table will now be first created and later on dropped again. Is it safe to remove the create and drop migrations down the road?

Comment: If no other migration uses that table (adding/removing columns, adjusting column attributes, etc.) then it might not harm anything to remove the create/drop migrations. However I'm not sure removing them will buy you any significant improvements. Is there some particular reason you're looking to remove them?

Comment: Any view here on whether it's better to drop tables or revert to a previous database schema?

Comment: If you're done with the table and do not plan to use it anymore, I'd say just drop it. Better to get rid of it if its not being used.

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table/31657066#31657066)  by @BederAcostaBorges is more self-explanatory and accurate

Comment: How to also remove all foreign keys? There are columns in other tables pointing to the table being dropped.

Comment: If you also want the migration to be reversible then add a block to the drop_table method that looks like what you would give to a create_table method, that way if you did a rollback the table structure would be created again http://joshfrankel.me/blog/ensure-dropping-a-database-table-is-reversible/

Comment: @Martin Konicek, I highly recommend removing foreign keys from associated models *before* running drop_table, eg. `remove_index :table_name, :associated_id` then `remove_column :table_name, :associated_id` then `drop_table :associated_table_name`.

Answer (score 392):

Write your migration manually. E.g. run `rails g migration DropUsers`.

As for the code of the migration I'm just gonna quote Maxwell Holder's post [Rails Migration Checklist](http://maxwellholder.com/blog/rails-migration-checklist)

## BAD - running `rake db:migrate` and then `rake db:rollback` will fail

```
class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

## GOOD - reveals intent that migration should not be reversible

```
class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :users
  end

  def down
    fail ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

## BETTER - is actually reversible

```
class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're cutting and pasting into the block from `schema.rb`, don't forget to also search `schema.rb` for foreign keys. Then add the foreign key definition to the `drop_table` block, e.g.: `t.foreign_key "other_table"`

Comment: I used the 3rd option and it worked perfectly fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank You @Beder Acosta Borges  I had been wondering how to properly do the migration where it was reversible.  In my case it was to remove 2 tables that were not needed.  So I basically generated the migration and copied the contents out of the original migration and changed the create_table to drop_table but left the do |t| block with all of the columns and it worked perfectly!  TY!

Answer (score 380):

First generate an empty migration with any name you'd like. It's important to do it this way since it creates the appropriate date.

```
rails generate migration DropProductsTable
```

This will generate a .rb file in /db/migrate/ like 20111015185025_drop_products_table.rb

Now edit that file to look like this:

```
class DropProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :products
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

The only thing I added was `drop_table :products` and `raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`.

Then run `rake db:migrate` and it'll drop the table for you.

Comment: A down migration should be used to recreate the table being dropped.

Comment: This migration could never be rolled back, even in development. Would it be better to just leave the down migration blank?

Comment: This is the better answer + fflyer's comment

Comment: @mjnissim and fflyer05 are correct, in order to avoid any weird thing you should recreate the table in the down method.

Comment: To make the migration reversible, modify the code as follows. I prefer to use the change method, instead of having a separate up and down method, so the same code works both ways
      `def change; `
        `drop_table :products do |t|;
          t.string :product_name, null: false;
          t.timestamps null: false;
        end;
      end;`

Comment: Dropping a table deletes all the data, if you recreate it in the `down` method you won't recover it so it's not actually a proper roll back. It's better to clearly indicate that the migration is irreversible than to give a false sense that it can be recovered from.

Answer (score 217):

**Warning**: Do this at your own risk, as @[z-atef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052097/z-atef) and @[nzifnab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649006/nzifnab) correctly point out, Rails will not be aware of these changes, your migration sequence fill fail and your schema will be different from your coworkers'. This is meant as a resource for locally  tinkering with development only.

---

While the answers provided here work properly, I wanted something a bit more 'straightforward', I found it here: [link](http://problemateek.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/drop-table-from-rails-console.html)
First enter rails console:

```
$rails console
```

Then just type:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
```

And done, worked for me!

Comment: The model is still there until you run `rails destroy model User`

Comment: Only run this if you want to get rid of the table for good. Rails will be unaware of this drop. Migration is broken after running this command. Can not CREATE, DROP...ETC. ERROR SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: accruals: DROP TABLE "sometable"

Comment: WARNING: DO NOT DO THIS. You should never ever perform DDL operations on your database straight from the console. Your  structure file will have no idea this change was made, your coworkers development environments will be different from your own and from production, it's just a mess. Use migrations.

Comment: Indeed, this should ***ONLY*** be done if the table ***ONLY*** exists on your local database, no one cares about the data in that table, and the migration has already been deleted and cannot be easily restored. Therefore it won't affect others with access to the repo. IE: The only time I do this if I generated the model, ran migrations then destroyed the scaffold (because of say a typo or something) without reversing the migration first. (faster to just delete the table than try to recover the deleted migration)

Answer (score 38):

You need to to create a new migration file using following command

```
rails generate migration drop_table_xyz
```

and write drop_table code in newly generated migration file (db/migration/xxxxxxx_drop_table_xyz) like

```
drop_table :tablename
```

Or if you wanted to drop table without migration, simply open rails console by

```
$ rails c
```

and execute following command

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("drop table table_name")
```

or you can use more simplified command

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
```

Answer (score 24):

1. rails g migration drop_users
2. edit the migration

```ruby
    class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        drop_table :users do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

3. rake db:migrate

Answer (score 17):

The simple and official way would be this:

```
  rails g migration drop_tablename
```

Now go to your db/migrate and look for your file which contains the drop_tablename as the filename and edit it to this.

```
    def change
      drop_table :table_name
    end
```

Then you need to run

```
    rake db:migrate
```

on your console.

Answer (score 15):

I wasn't able to make it work with migration script so I went ahead with this solution. Enter rails console using the terminal:

```
rails c
```

Type

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:tablename)
```

It works well for me. This will remove the previous table. Don't forget to run

```
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 14):

I think, to be completely "official", you would need to create a new migration, and put drop_table in self.up. The self.down method should then contain all the code to recreate the table in full. Presumably that code could just be taken from schema.rb at the time you create the migration.

It seems a little odd, to put in code to create a table you know you aren't going to need anymore, but that would keep all the migration code complete and "official", right?

I just did this for a table I needed to drop, but honestly didn't test the "down" and not sure why I would.

Comment: Strange but it looks like I'm going to have to do this too.

Comment: Or you can just use: `raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` in the self.down method, so you at LEAST give yourself an error / notice if you ever try to rollback.

Comment: I would test the down just because otherwise I'm introducing untested code into my project.  How can I reuse the original migration's up method?  I've tried `CreateMyTable.up` and `ActiveRecord::Migrator.run(:up, ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths, X)` where X is the migration that originally created the table, but neither works--in both approaches, AR first checks whether the migration has already been applied, and silently skips it if it has.
`

Answer (score 14):

you can simply drop a table from rails console.
first open the console

```
$ rails c
```

then paste this command in console

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:table_name)
```

replace **table_name** with the table you want to delete.

you can also drop table directly from the terminal. just enter in the root directory of your application and run this command

```
$ rails runner "Util::Table.clobber 'table_name'"
```

Answer (score 13):

You can roll back a migration the way it is in the guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#reverting-previous-migrations

Generate a migration:

```
rails generate migration revert_create_tablename
```

Write the migration:

```
require_relative '20121212123456_create_tablename'

class RevertCreateTablename < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    revert CreateTablename    
  end
end
```

This way you can also rollback and can use to revert any migration

Answer (score 12):

Alternative to raising exception or attempting to recreate a now empty table  - while still enabling migration rollback, redo etc -

```
def change
  drop_table(:users, force: true) if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?('users')
end
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't simply run `drop_table :table_name`, instead you can create an empty migration by running:
`rails g migration DropInstalls`

You can then add this into that empty migration:

```
class DropInstalls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :installs
  end
end
```

Then run `rails db:migrate` in the command line which should remove the Installs table
The solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711180/14103174)

Comment: Let me know if you have any q's, will try to answer asap

Answer (score 6):

Open you rails console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("drop table table_name")
```

Answer (score 5):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_table :table_name`

Comment: If you are working in a development environment this is a much easier solution than answers with more votes

Answer (score 2):

I needed to delete our migration scripts along with the tables themselves ...

```
class Util::Table < ActiveRecord::Migration

 def self.clobber(table_name)   
    # drop the table
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? table_name
      puts "\n== " + table_name.upcase.cyan + " ! " 
           << Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S").yellow
      drop_table table_name 
    end

    # locate any existing migrations for a table and delete them
    base_folder = File.join(Rails.root.to_s, 'db', 'migrate')
    Dir[File.join(base_folder, '**', '*.rb')].each do |file|
      if file =~ /create_#{table_name}.rb/
        puts "== deleting migration: " + file.cyan + " ! "
             << Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S").yellow
        FileUtils.rm_rf(file)
        break
      end
    end
  end

  def self.clobber_all
    # delete every table in the db, along with every corresponding migration 
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each {|t| clobber t}
  end

end
```

from terminal window run:

```
$ rails runner "Util::Table.clobber 'your_table_name'"
```

or

```
$ rails runner "Util::Table.clobber_all"
```

Answer (score 2):

if anybody is looking for how to do it in SQL.

type `rails dbconsole` from terminal

enter password

In console do

`USE db_name;`

`DROP TABLE table_name;`

`exit`

Please dont forget to remove the migration file and table structure from schema

Comment: You can also open it by typing just `rails db`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[Helpful documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-drop_table)</kbd>

In migration you can drop table by:

```
drop_table(table_name, **options)
```

options:

`:force`
Set to :cascade to drop dependent objects as well. Defaults to false

`:if_exists`
Set to true to only drop the table if it exists. Defaults to false

Example:

1. Create migration for drop table, for example we are want to drop `User` table

   ```
   rails g migration DropUsers

   Running via Spring preloader in process 13189
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20211110174028_drop_users.rb
   ```
2. Edit migration file, in our case it is `db/migrate/20211110174028_drop_users.rb`

   ```
   class DropUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
     def change
       drop_table :users, if_exist: true
     end
   end
   ```
3. Run migration for dropping `User` table

   ```
   rails db:migrate

   == 20211110174028 DropUsers: migrating ===============================
   -- drop_table(:users, {:if_exist=>true})
      -> 0.4607s
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<version>
```

Where `<version>` is the version number of your migration file you want to revert.

Example:-

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=3846656238
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way you can do is

```
rails g migration Drop_table_Users
```

then  do the following

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

**Run this command:-**

```
rails g migration drop_table_name
```

then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

**or if you are using MySql database then:**

1. login with database
2. `show databases;`
3. `show tables;`
4. `drop table_name;`

Comment: Does this answer add anything to the existing, accepted answer? If not, there's no need to post this.

Comment: this creates an empty migration in rails 4.2, as already stated in the question itself.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what the OP originally tried...this answer should be removed

Comment: Adding a simple answer does not deserve to be downvoted. It still is relevant, I guess. Be kind to newer users please.

Answer (score -1):

**Drop Table/Migration**

run:-
$ rails generate migration DropTablename

exp:- $ rails generate migration DropProducts

Answer (score -1):

if you want to drop a specific table you can do

```
$ rails db:migrate:up VERSION=[Here you can insert timestamp of table]
```

otherwise if you want to drop all your database you can do

```
$rails db:drop
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to delete the table from the schema perform below operation --

```
rails db:rollback
```

Comment: This command will only undo the last migrate command. If that command is the creation of the table, it will drop the table. But unless you then delete the migration file that creates it, it will be recreated the at the next `db:migrate`.

Keeping your migrations in order to replicate elsewhere is important, especially if work has been done in the meantime. Using `db:rollback` to change the final database layout is almost guaranteed to ruin many people's work.