# Drop_table problem preventing rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, drop-table

I was looking for a way to drop a table in Rails and start fresh and came across this answer: [Rails DB Migration - How To Drop a Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table)

However, when I ran `drop_table :examples` I got the following error:

```
-bash: drop_table: command not found
```

Here's my `create_examples` migrate file:

```
def self.down
  drop_table :examples
end
```

Can anyone help guide me into fixing this and give me insight on what I'm doing wrong? I need to fix it because this particular migrate is preventing from doing a `rake db:migrate`, generating the following error:

```
==  CreateExamples: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:examples)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "examples" already exists: CREATE TABLE "examples" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "content" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)
```

Thanks! (And if I need to provide more code let me know.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be dropping your old table right before creating the new version:

```
def self.up
    drop_table :examples
    create_table :examples do |t|
        #...
    end
end
```

And since you can't really reverse that `drop_table`, you might want to raise an exception in the rollback:

```
def self.down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
```

Or maybe you just want to keep your current `self.down`.