# Rails 3: Drop a table using migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a table that I created using the migrations, now I want to get rid of this table.  I'm pretty sure I can just back out that migration, but I can't find the syntax to do that.  I found this question from searching [Rails DB Migration - How To Drop a Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table)

but he basically says you can find what you need and provides a link.  I read that link and I didn't see anything that says how to do it.  I saw pieces of it, but I don't know how to put them together.

I see in the migration it has a self.down method, I really just need to know how to call that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rollback the last migration with:

`rake db:rollback`

That will run the `self.down` method, which should be `drop_table :table_name`

Comment: What if it was a migration I ran last month and I've done a bunch more since then?

Comment: @jhorra...I believe u r better off writing a new migration file having `drop_table :table_name` in the `up` method, and `create_table :table_name` in the `down` method in that case and run the migration. This way, any other person using the same project will get the table dropped, when he uses `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ok, I'll go the new migration route

Answer (score 16):

Try to create an empty migration and use:

```
drop_table :table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n
```

where n is the number of steps you need to roll back.  If you leave the STEP off it just rolls back 1.

To migrate to a particular version, use:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20080906120000
```

If you want to quickly apply a table drop, you could create a new migration, run it, then delete it along with the original migration you no longer want.  The syntax for dropping a table is:

```
drop_table :table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the model is not the best way.

Instead, run this command in your rails console: `rake db:rollback`

(to access the rails console, type `rails c` in a terminal as shown [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console))

Answer (score -11):

You can remove a table using rake to destroy the model:

```
rails destroy model your_model
```

Comment: A Rails model is not a table, nor any other part of the database. While commanding `generate model Foo` creates a corresponding database migration for creating a table for storing instances of Foo, commanding `destroy model Foo` doesn't destroy the table.  As http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=10961#p10961 says: "Beware, though - when you generate a model, it creates a database migration. If you run 'destroy' on that model, it will delete the migration file, but not the database table. ..."