# Heroku - how to remove table and run migration again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I just discovered that one of my tables in Heroku app has a different structure than the one on my localhost.

In the best way I would need to run the migration that create a new table again, but what is the best way to do that?

Just simply manually remove the table in Heroku terminal and then change the date of migration and run it again?

Comment: I think you will need to create a migration to drop that table and then create a migration to make it again. Look at the answer number 2: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table) I hope someone with more experience will help you more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can redo a single migration file like this:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20130311054546
```

where 20130311054546 is the timestamp of your migration.

To do different database modifications, such as `drop table` etc., I usually use  [David Dollar's heroku SQL console](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console)

Comment: Thank you Frank, this is exactly what I have been looking for.