# Schema file ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've dropped my table successfully from the database from the console, using

`ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:foo)`,

But for some reason the table data still shows in the schema file.

I would like a method to do this without having to manually remove the data, (Doesn't give a proper rails feeling to it.)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table

Comment: no, not really, doesn't mention schema file anywhere in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The schema file located in `db/schema.rb` was most likely generated the very last time you ran `rake db:migrate`.  This is because `rake db:migrate` migrates your db through all of the migrations in your `db/migrate` folder, **and then it calls the `db:schema:dump` task**, which generates the schema file based on the current state of the database.

For your situation, after you have run `ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:foo)` in the rails console, the current state of your database (now, no longer having the table `foo`) is not in sync with the `schema.rb` file that was generated when you last migrated.

What you want to do at this point is re-dump the schema based on the current state of the database, and you do this by running `rake db:schema:dump`.  This will take the current state of your database (without the table `foo`) and generate your `db/schema.rb` file.

For more information on the schema file and its relationship to migrations, I would recommend looking at the [Rails Guide on Active Record Migrations: Schema Dumping and You](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you).

Comment: Wow Alvin, that was amazingly clear advice, and solution, well answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

While the answers provided here work properly, I wanted something a bit more 'straightforward', I found it here: [link](http://problemateek.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/drop-table-from-rails-console.html)
First enter rails console:

```
$rails console
```

Then just type:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:foo)
```

Where `:foo` is the table name. And done, worked for me!