# I'm trying to use devise with pg '0.15.1'. When I try to run migration I get the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

Error

```
 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" character varying(255)
```

Migration file

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Comment: The error code is pretty straight forward....the table 'users' already exists.  [Drop the table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table) and try your migration again

Comment: Ive tried deleting the table and it didn't help. This is my migration.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting.

Comment: Could you enter your dbconsole (type `rails dbconsole`) and show me the list of tables (while in dbconsole type `\d`)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and reply JTG! I managed to sort it, not overly sure how. Still onwards and upwards.