# Deleting table from schema - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I want to delete a table in my schema. I created the database when I first started the project and want the table removed. What is the best way of doing this?

I tried `rails g migration drop table :installs` but that just creates a empty migration?

**Schema:**

```
create_table "installs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

add_index "installs", ["email"], name: "index_installs_on_email", unique: true
add_index "installs", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_installs_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails DB Migration - How To Drop a Table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table)

Comment: I'd say that it isn't quite a duplicate in that this is a question about the schema (even if that isn't what should be edited).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you create an empty migration by running: 

`rails g migration DropInstalls`

 *or:* 

`rails generate migration DropInstalls`

You can then add this into that empty migration:

```
class DropInstalls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :installs
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` in the command line which should remove the Installs table

Note: `db/schema.rb` is an autogenerated file. To alter the db structure, you should use the migrations instead of attempting to edit the schema file.

Comment: This answer would be more complete if it pointed out that the schema is an autogenerated file and therefore the wrong thing to be looking at.