# Ruby on Rails 5.0 Table removal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently working on a project and I have messed up my code. I went back and deleted the git branch. I am now going back through and adding all of the code back.

I need to create a db migration but the migration that I need to create says it already exists. I don't see how this could be possible.

My question is how would I get rails to just overwrite the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you deleted your git branch and local code, if you didn't delete your database, it remains the same so your table still exists.

You can create a migration to drop a table.
Code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7779954/4235383) answer.

```
rails generate migration DropProductsTable

class DropProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :products
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

I don't know what database you are using, but if the table is the same as what you want to add you may not even need to drop it.

Comment: I see. I am currently working through a bootcamp course and I messed up the branch so I deleted it. The database I am using is SQLite3. So if the data for the table is the same as the first one I can just leave it?

Comment: This was my out put

redhoodjt:~/workspace/saasapp (contact_form) $ rails db:migrate
== 20170223181245 CreateContacts: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:contacts)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Comment: Yes. Your database hasn't been touched even though you deleted the branch so the table is still there. You could also use ` rake db:rollback` to undo the last migration you made, or `rake db:rollback STEP=n` (n being the number of migrations to rollback) depending on when you created this table. Then `rake db:migrate` with your new migrations that you've created.

Comment: The only problem with that is that for some reason the error that I am being given says that all later migrations canceled.

Comment: Yes. If you have 3 migration files and the first one gives you the error because the table is already there, the 2 that come after it will get cancelled. You need to resolve the issue with the problem migration by dropping the table/rolling back or removing the migration file. Is the original migration that you made for this table still there, or did you delete it?

Comment: I deleted it. At least I think that I did.

Comment: Ok I deleted it and that fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: But now I have another issue. When I try to see if my submission form works I get an error saying:

No route matches [POST]"/contacts/new"

When I go to my routes.rb file though I have resources :contacts in there.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is impossible to give you an answer for that.

Comment: Ok. I can post it. How do I post code so it shows up like code? And from what file or files do you need the code from?

Comment: Lets continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136554/no-route-matches-post)

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough to chat.

Comment: Ok that's a pain. You should post this as a new question then, add the form code from your view, routes, and new and create controller methods