# Remove Model and Table so can start again in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, polymorphic-associations, rails-migrations, destroy

I created a model for comments at the start of a project, but have now come to the realisation I need to create some polymorphic relations so I can use comments with a number of other models as well.  Considering the the code I already have etc, I'm thinking it might be easier for me to just start again from scratch so I can build all the views/controllers etc in the correct way for my new polymorphic world.

I see that I can run `rails destroy model comments` to achieve this but I have two questions on that:

1. Will this delete the model, migrations AND the actual DB table?
2. What are the implications when I want to create a new model with the exact same name?

Comment: [You have the solution here to drop the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7779954/5015341)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to completely remove all columns &
tables that migration has created you need to run:

`rails db:migrate:down VERSION=012345678` (where 012345678 should be the version number of your migration)

.............................

`rails destroy model Comments`

will delete your Model, pending migration, tests and fixtures

So destroy it's the opposite of generate:

```
$ bin/rails destroy model Oops
      invoke  active_record
      remove    db/migrate/20120528062523_create_oops.rb
      remove    app/models/oops.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      remove      test/models/oops_test.rb
      remove      test/fixtures/oops.yml
```

And, you can now create a new Model with the same name, as there's no trace of your previous one :)

Comment: I'm not getting this behavior in Rails 6. the `destroy model` generator does not remove the `create` migration for the associated model. And it shouldn't! Rails isn't analyzing subsequent migrations to ensure that they don't rely on the destroyed model.

The Rails way here is to destroy the model and if you want to get rid of the associated table, create a new db migration with the line `drop_table :table_name`. This preserves the integrity of your migration history, which is intended to be the source of truth for your schema. Always go forward with your migrations.

Answer (score 5):

**If you have already migrated the database after creating the model:**

First, rollback the changes to the database:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100905201547
```

where *version* is the timestamp identifying the migration. For example, if your migration file is called *20170411182948_create_comments.rb* then your version parameter should be *20170411182948*

Then run

```
rails destroy model comments
```

The first command will delete the table from the actual database. The second command will delete the model and the migration file. Make sure you run them in that order as the first command is dependent on the migration file to perform the rollback (which is deleted during the second command).

**If you have have not migrated the database:**

The table would not have been added to your database. You can go ahead and delete your model and migration files manually or use the destroy command.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to remove the table thoroughly.
Run this :

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
```

Then :

```
sqlite> drop table table_name;
sqlite> .quit
```