# how i can remove tables my.sql by ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

how i can rollback or remove this formula clean im try def up and def down but not migrate

```
 class AllowAllTrackersAsSubtasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    trackers = Tracker.all
    trackers_ids = trackers.pluck(:id)
    trackers.each do |tracker|
      tracker.subtask_ids = trackers_ids
      tracker.save
    end
  end
end
```

this another code

```
class CreateTrackerSubtask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table "trackers_subtasks", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
      t.column "tracker_id", :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.column "subtask_id", :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.index [:tracker_id, :subtask_id], :unique => true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you create a migration to remove the table?  Is there some reason that isn't an option?

Comment: yes,but i want remove what im do,how i can drop table,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020131/rails-db-migration-how-to-drop-a-table#:~:text=First%20generate%20an%20empty%20migration,it%20creates%20the%20appropriate%20date.&text=The%20only%20thing%20I%20added,drop%20the%20table%20for%20you.

Comment: class CreateTrackerSubtask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    drop_table "trackers_subtasks", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
      t.column "tracker_id", :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.column "subtask_id", :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.index [:tracker_id, :subtask_id], :unique => true
    end
  end

Answer (score -1):

this code work??

```
class CreateTrackerSubtask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    drop_table "trackers_subtasks", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
      t.column "tracker_id", :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.column "subtask_id", :integer, :default => 0, :null => false
      t.index [:tracker_id, :subtask_id], :unique => true
    end
  end
```

what another code how i can do?

Comment: What happened when you ran that, did it work?  It is a little unclear if you are asking if this would work or if it did work.

Comment: yes i want drop all things im do it in my database without effect